# BottomNavigationView - How to get selected menu item?

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I used BottomNavigationView to switch fragments. How to get currently selected menu item, to prevent reopening fragment ?

```
        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView)
                findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);

        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.action_1:
                                // open fragment 1
                                break;
                            case R.id.action_2:
                                // open fragment 2
                                break;
                            case R.id.action_3:
                                // open fragment 3
                                break;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
    }
```

Comment: Can you be more clear about ' prevent reopening fragment'? 
What do you expect on Navigation Item (Menu) click?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Solution:

```
private int getSelectedItem(BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView) {
    Menu menu = bottomNavigationView.getMenu();
    for (int i = 0; i < bottomNavigationView.getMenu().size(); i++) {
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.getItem(i);
        if (menuItem.isChecked()) {
            return menuItem.getItemId();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 29):

Get selected item at first and then `getMenu().findItem(int itemId)`

```
bottomNavigationView.getMenu().findItem(bottomNavigationView.getSelectedItemId())
```

Answer (score 9):

Get the currently selected menu item ID using [`getSelectedItemId`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html#getSelectedItemId()):

```
int selectedItemId = bottomNavigationView.getSelectedItemId();
MenuItem selectedItem = bottomNavigationView.getMenu().findItem(selectedItemId);
```

This method started being available from Android Support Library 25.3.0.

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest solution for checking if the previous item is the next item is this:

```
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);

bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(
    new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            final int previousItem = bottomNavigationView.getSelectedItemId();
            final int nextItem = item.getItemId();
            if (previousItem != nextItem) {
                 switch (nextItem) {
                     case R.id.action_1:
                         // open fragment 1
                         break;
                     case R.id.action_2:
                         // open fragment 2
                         break;
                     case R.id.action_3:
                         // open fragment 3
                         break;
                 }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
);
```

Note that there is no need for iterating, and that `onNavigationItemSelected` returns `true`, because the function consumes the event.

I hope it helps someone.