# Change background color of single item in BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I would like to make one item on a `BottomNavigationView` visually stand out. Is it possible to change the background color of a single item in a `BottomNavigationView`?

Comment: u want if selected it, and after that, the background is changed?

Comment: No, I would like the background of one single item to be in a different color always.

Comment: so you can get position and setBackGroundColor

Comment: @sanaebadi and how would I do that? :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41459050/bottomnavigationview-how-to-get-selected-menu-item